# Can blog post be exported to a Word doc and retain formatting?

Tags: list, export, word

I am both new to this company, and relatively new to SharePoint.  We are using a blog to collaborate on "items".  As part of the collaboration process, formatting -- such as text color, strike-through, etc. -- is used to designate changes.  1) Is there a way to export this information to a Word doc and 2) still retain this formatting?  Additionally, there are about 20-25 posts but we would like them all exported/appended to the same document.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste works, little more time intensive but you don't have that many posts.

Also, you may want to look into Wikis for collaborative editing of "items"